# How i can execute a function of Jquery each time page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, load, refresh, setinterval, document-ready

My website is constantly loading content when you go to the bottom of this.
And i have the next Jquery (is not important what it does)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".info").each(function(e) { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('o', 'e')); 
    }); 
});
```

That script replaces all "o" to "e". The problem is that it only executes once, and i would like that this execute each time that the browser has loaded something, in this case, when you go to the bottom of the website.
At the moment, i use this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".info").each(function(e) { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('ó', 'o')); 
        }); 
    });
}, 6000);
```

Each 6 seconds, that script is executed but is not an optimal solution.
I know that exist a solution based in PHP, but i don't understand PHP yet.
Do you know a solution? thanks you in advance

Comment: Use the callback function of your content loader.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery ajax and rendered data then,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".info").each(function (e) {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('ó', 'o'));
        });

        $('#selector').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/your_path', type: 'Get',
                data: {}, //Optional 
                success: function (data) {
                    $('body').append(data);

                    $(".info").each(function (e) {
                        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('ó', 'o'));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: browser has loaded something? using like jquery ajax and in which event?

Comment: i'm sorry for the delay my answer. Before all, i really appreciate your answer, but i don't handling .ajax's Jquery, well.. to be specific, i don't understand "url: '/your_path', type: 'Get'" and "data: {}" How it works? And.. yes, browser load all the document at the beginning, but it load something new when you go to the bottom of the website (it's for replace "go to next page". For be specific, sadly i'm working on tumblr if you know it, and that is called InfiniteScrolling or AutoPage, for that reason i can't do a jsfiddle). Sorry if I ask too much ): thanks